# Getting the index from a split in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

The [help for the AnyLogic split](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/split.html) function says

> There are two “extension points” where you can setup a new agent: its
> construction code **New agent (copy)** and **On exit copy** code. In
> both places you can access the original agent as `original` and
> the index of the new agent as `index`.

However, I tried `index`, `agent.index`, and `agent.index()` but got error messages:

- index cannot be resolved to a variable
- index cannot be resolved or is not a field
- The method index() is undefined for the type Card

respectively.

The ctrl-space context menu does show that there's an `index` object:
[image: index object context menu]

But this doesn't seem to have any methods or variables.

And using the context menu on agent only gives `agent.getIndex()` as a method:
[image: agent getIndex context menu]

However, this doesn't give me the index of the output of the split. Instead, it gives a number that I struggle to understand. I added this to a dataset with `dataset.add(agent.getIndex());` in the **On exit copy** of the split block and got this:

[image: dataset for agent.getIndex()]

In this split, I was creating 10 copies of the new agent, so I was expecting the numbers 1-10 repeated with each split. Instead, I get 2-11 and then 8-17, and then other numbers generally getting bigger (what are these numbers anyway?!). My overall MWE here is:

[image: MWE for split index behavior]

What I'm actually trying to achieve here is for:

- an agent to arrive at split,
- 10 new agents to be generated at the copy of the split,
- the original agent to be held (at a hold block)...
- until the 10 agents have gone through the delay

So delay2 has (in the **On at exit)**:

```
if(agent.lastCard){
    hold.unblock();
}
```

while the split has (in the **On exit copy**):

```
if(agent.getIndex()==10){
    agent.lastCard = true;
}
```

where agent refers to a `Card` agent that has a boolean variable called `lastCard` which defaults to false.

So the basic question is how to get the index of the copies coming out of split. And the alternative question is how to achieve the goal outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was another easily solved problem. The key is to use `indexCopy`. Note that indexCopy is indexed from 0 to $n-1$